# Material UI Switch set according to value, but still switchable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use a Material UI switch (using Typescript) to display a status value (active/inactive) on my edit page, and have it switchable to change the status.  So far I can either get the the switch to display the value OR may it switchable, I can't get both to work together.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**ToggleSwitch.tsx**

```
export default function ToggleSwitch(props) {
  const { label1, label2, curValue} = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

  const handleSwitch = e => {
       setChecked(e.target.checked);
  };

 console.log(curVal);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography>
        {label1}
        {<Switch 
          checked={checked}
          onChange={handleSwitch}
          color='primary'
          inputProps={{'aria-label': 'switch'}}
          />}
        {label2}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

The DB was originally written in Oracle, so the value of *isActive* is "0" or "1" rather than "true" or "false", hence my *curVal* variable.

**EditPage.tsx**

```
const curVal = item.isActive === 1 ? true : false;

<Controls.ToggleSwitch
   label1='Inactive'
   label2='Active'
   curValue={curVal}
/>
```

I tried using my *curVal* variable as the state rather than putting "true", it always seemed to default the switch to unchecked.
The console.log, is logging the value twice, he first time always says "False", but the second long with show the current value.  So it seems like the *curVal* is rendering after the rest of the page.

How do I handle this were it will display the current value of *isActive* but still allow me to switch the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using an API call in order to get item from server, That is why `curVal` does not have the correct initial value.

I can think of two ways you can solve this problem:

#### 1. Don't render `ToggleSwitch` until `item.isActive` is initialized:

```
{item.isActive !== undefined ? <Controls.ToggleSwitch
   label1='Inactive'
   label2='Active'
   curValue={curVal}
/> : null}
```

And then you can use `curVal` as the initial value for `useState`.

#### 2. Update `ToggleSwitch` state on each props update:

```
// inside ToggleSwitch
useEffect(() => {
  setChecked(curValue);
}, [curValue])
```

This will update `checked` on each change coming from `item.isActive`

Note: Your `Switch` is controlled so you should not be using `defaultChecked`

Comment: I used your second option so i didn't have to duplicate the code on each page I have a switch on and it worked like I charm  I was just starting to look into using useEffect, but was trying to call props rather than curValue.  Thank You!